# Wikibase language links

Tags: localization, mediawiki, wikibase

In a custom installation of wikibase I have links to wikipedia and my wiki family. In the left sidebar the language links to the wikis in my family do not show up as desired but with their wiki prefix and the name of the page. So at the german site it shows "enimed:Main Page" instead of "english".

Comment: I believe this is not specific to wikibase, so you might want to add mediawiki as a tag. Also, I doubt people will be able to help you if you don't include some basic details. Such as: what are the relevant config parameters set to? Are you using dark  $wgInterwikiMagic? What does your interwiki table/list look like etc.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I will provide the information.

Answer (score 0):

The desired effect is achieved when adding the wiki prefixes to `$wgExtraInterlanguageLinkPrefixes`

```
$wgExtraInterlanguageLinkPrefixes[]="enimed";
$wgExtraInterlanguageLinkPrefixes[]="deimed";
```

Then creating system messages for the extra language links. I have created a page "MediaWiki:Interlanguage-link-deimed" with the content "deutsch" and a page "MediaWiki:Interlanguage-link-enimed" with the content "english".

I don't know if thats the best way to go. Therefore I'll leave the question open for now.